# How to get difference between two dataframes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get difference between two dataframes. I tried two solutions but both the solution are giving me wrong result. Could you please help me what and where am I doing wrong?

I tried below two solutions-

```
df_diff = df1[~df1.astype(str).apply(tuple,1).isin(df2.astype(str).apply(tuple,1))]

df_diff = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

df1:

```
Program Name|Updated Time|Published Time|Modified Time|Project Number|Strength|Indication|Brand Name|Generic Name|Therapeutic Area|Manufacturer Requested Reimbursement Criteria|Biosimilar|Manufacturer|Submission received|Submission accepted|Review initiated|Submission Type|Companion Diagnostics|Recommendation Date|Recommendation Type|Fee Schedule|Patient group input closed|Patient group input closed clarification|Submission Deemed Complete Target Date|Submission Deemed Complete Target Date Clarification|Submission Deemed Complete Actual Date|Submission Deemed Complete Actual Date Clarification|Call for Patient Input Date|Call for Patient Input Date Clarification|Patient Group Input Submission Received Date|Patient Group Input Submission Received Date Clarification|Patient input summary sent for review to patient input groups|Patient input summary sent for review to patient input groups clarification|Patient Group Input Summary Comment Received Date|Patient Group Input Summary Comment Received Date Clarification|CADTH Reviewers Report sent to Manufacturer Date|CADTH Reviewers Report sent to Manufacturer Date Clarification|Deadline for sponsors comments|Deadline for sponsors comments Clarification|Comments from Manufacturers on Reviewerâ€™s Report Date|Comments from Manufacturers on Reviewerâ€™s Report Date Clarification|Redaction Response from Manufacturer on Report Received by CADTH Date|Redaction Response from Manufacturer on Report Received by CADTH Date Clarification|CDEC Meeting Date|CDEC Meeting Date Clarification|Final recommendation issued to sponsor and drug plans|Final recommendation issued to sponsor and drug plans Clarification|Embargo Period Date|Embargo Period Date Clarification|Embargo period ended|Embargo period ended clarification|Reconsideration Meeting Date|Reconsideration Meeting Date Clarification|Final Recommendation Sent to Drug Plans and Manufacturer Date|Final recommendation posted|Reconsideration Requested|Reconsideration Requested Clarification|Deadline for sponsor to submit redaction requests on draft CADTH review report(s)|CADTH review report(s) posted|CDE_rec_crdt_dt|Cde_Rec_effctv_strt_dt|Cde_Rec_effec_end_dt
Non Oncology Pharmaceuticals|2020-12-08T23:17:00-05:00|2014-06-03T10:12:32-04:00|2020-12-08T23:17:00-05:00|SE0383-000||Ankylosing spondylitis, plaque psoriasis, psoriatic arthritis, rheumatoid arthritis|Remsima|Infliximab|Ankylosing spondylitis- arthritis, psoriatic- arthritis, rheumatoid- plaque psoriasis||Yes|Fresenius Kabi Canada||||Initial|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||2021-04-08|2021-04-08|
```

df2:

```
Program Name|Updated Time|Published Time|Modified Time|Project Number|Strength|Indication|Brand Name|Generic Name|Therapeutic Area|Manufacturer Requested Reimbursement Criteria|Biosimilar|Manufacturer|Submission received|Submission accepted|Review initiated|Submission Type|Companion Diagnostics|Recommendation Date|Recommendation Type|Fee Schedule|Patient group input closed|Patient group input closed clarification|Submission Deemed Complete Target Date|Submission Deemed Complete Target Date Clarification|Submission Deemed Complete Actual Date|Submission Deemed Complete Actual Date Clarification|Call for Patient Input Date|Call for Patient Input Date Clarification|Patient Group Input Submission Received Date|Patient Group Input Submission Received Date Clarification|Patient input summary sent for review to patient input groups|Patient input summary sent for review to patient input groups clarification|Patient Group Input Summary Comment Received Date|Patient Group Input Summary Comment Received Date Clarification|CADTH Reviewers Report sent to Manufacturer Date|CADTH Reviewers Report sent to Manufacturer Date Clarification|Deadline for sponsors comments|Deadline for sponsors comments Clarification|Comments from Manufacturers on Reviewerâ€™s Report Date|Comments from Manufacturers on Reviewerâ€™s Report Date Clarification|Redaction Response from Manufacturer on Report Received by CADTH Date|Redaction Response from Manufacturer on Report Received by CADTH Date Clarification|CDEC Meeting Date|CDEC Meeting Date Clarification|Final recommendation issued to sponsor and drug plans|Final recommendation issued to sponsor and drug plans Clarification|Embargo Period Date|Embargo Period Date Clarification|Embargo period ended|Embargo period ended clarification|Reconsideration Meeting Date|Reconsideration Meeting Date Clarification|Final Recommendation Sent to Drug Plans and Manufacturer Date|Final recommendation posted|Reconsideration Requested|Reconsideration Requested Clarification|Deadline for sponsor to submit redaction requests on draft CADTH review report(s)|CADTH review report(s) posted|CDE_rec_crdt_dt|Cde_Rec_effctv_strt_dt|Cde_Rec_effec_end_dt
Non Oncology Pharmaceuticals|2020-12-08T23:17:00-05:00|2014-06-03T10:12:32-04:00|2020-12-08T23:17:00-05:00|SE0383-000||Ankylosing spondylitis, plaque psoriasis, psoriatic arthritis, rheumatoid arthritis|Remsima|Infliximab|Ankylosing spondylitis- arthritis, psoriatic- arthritis, rheumatoid- plaque psoriasis||Yes|Fresenius Kabi Canada||||Initial|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||2021-04-08|2021-04-08|
```

In resultant df_diff should be blank but giving me wrong result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are missing values, so possible solution should be replace them to same values in both and compare with [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all `True`s per rows:

```
s1 = df1.fillna('missing').stack()
s2 = df2.fillna('missing').stack()

df_diff = s1[s1.ne(s2)]

df_diff1 = s2[s1.ne(s2)]
```

EDIT:

```
df_diff = pd.DataFrame() if df1.fillna('missing').equals(df1.fillna('missing')) else df1
```

Comment: is 'mask' equal to df_diff?

Comment: @ShivikaPatel - yes, you are right, sorry.

Comment: Still my df_diff is not empty.

Comment: @ShivikaPatel - Yes, so need if match? Then remove `~`

Comment: if I am removing ~ then it is not giving the difference. I changed one column value and df_diff generating empty.

Comment: @ShivikaPatel - If check one column what is expected ouput?

Comment: suppose in comparin df1 with df2, if any of the column value is not matching then in df_diff will print the value of df1

Comment: @ShivikaPatel - Can you test now?

Comment: can we use 'equals' between 2 dataframes to check equality?

Comment: @ShivikaPatel - If use [`Series.equals`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.equals.html) it is possible, but ouput is `True` if same or `False` if not. If need also what is different, need solution above.

Comment: if both df1 & df2 are identical means every column value is same then df_diff will be empty and both are not identical then df_diff = df1

Comment: @ShivikaPatel - So need `df_diff = pd.DataFrame() if df1.fillna('missing').equals(df1.fillna('missing')) else df1` ? Added to answer.